# how to generate a list where a column is twice as large as the other column in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sample database which you can view here: https://class.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/db/asset/socialdata.html

and I am trying to write an sql statement that does the following: 
/*Display a list of students who are friends with someone at least two years older then themselves. Do not list any pair more than once*/

this is the code i have so far:

```
SELECT distinct 
  A.name, 
  B.name, 
  A.grade, 
  B.grade 
FROM 
  Highschooler A, 
  Highschooler B, 
  Friend F 
WHERE 
  A.ID = F.ID1 AND 
  B.ID = F.ID2 AND 
  B.grade > A.grade 
ORDER BY 
  B.name, 
  B. grade, 
  A.name, 
  A.grade ASC;
```

This is what I am getting:

```
Cassandra   Alexis  9   11
Tiffany         Alexis  9   11
Gabriel         Andrew  9   10
Andrew          Austin  10  11
Andrew          Jordan  10  12
Austin          Kyle    11  12
Jessica         Kyle    11  12
```

It seems like its working, but the last four entries are only 1 year older not 2. Can anyone help steer me in the right direction or tell me if I Already have it right? I appreciate any help.

Comment: are you taking the Stanford class2go Introduction to Databases class?

Comment: No but the instructor of the database class I am taking in UNCA is using portions of that Stanford class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT distinct 
  A.name, 
  B.name, 
  A.grade, 
  B.grade 
FROM 
  Highschooler A, 
  Highschooler B, 
  Friend F 
WHERE 
  A.ID = F.ID1 AND 
  B.ID = F.ID2 AND 
  B.grade - A.grade >= 2
ORDER BY 
  B.name, 
  B. grade, 
  A.name, 
  A.grade ASC;
```

Comment: nearly - would you not also need to account for A.grade being greater than b.grade ?

Comment: @Trent I don't think so, because it's basically a cross product.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT distinct 
  A.name, 
  B.name, 
  A.grade, 
  B.grade 
FROM 
  Highschooler A, 
  Highschooler B, 
  Friend F 
WHERE 
  A.ID = F.ID1 AND 
  B.ID = F.ID2 AND 
  -- check both ways
  (B.grade - A.grade >= 2 OR  A.grade - B.grade >= 2)
ORDER BY 
  B.name, 
  B. grade, 
  A.name, 
  A.grade ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select hs1.name, hs1.grade, hs2.name, hs2.grade
From highschooler hs1
join likes L on L.id1 = hs1.id
join highschooler hs2 on L.id2 = hs2.id
Where hs1.grade - hs2.grade >= 2
```